# MySql environment variable on windows

Tags: mysql, windows, environment-variables, localhost

I have installed Mysql on my localhost and it works fine with phpMyAdmin. I have set my CLASSPATH to C:\xampp\mysql\bin\ but when I try and run 'mysql' from the command line it doesnt recognise it. If I navigate to C:\xampp\mysql\bin\ in the command line I can run mysql commands fine.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to PATH variable, not CLASSPATH.